# React Native project showing error when I run it using "react-native run-ios"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

1. Installed react-native
2. Created a project with "react-native init myproj"
3. After that I tried to run the project using "react-native run-ios"

It fails here with the error below:

> Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
>   /Users/blaze/Desktop/prasa/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
> Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c
>   Print:CFBundleIdentifier
>   build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/prasa.app/Info.plist Print:
>   Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add the whole error section

Comment: had the same issue, not sure what's going on

Comment: open the ios project in x code. check all dependencies. Check if the ios project builds successfully.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the iOS/build directory
2. Reset content and settings in the iOS simulator

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with the `react-native upgrade` command, which helped me reset some details in various xcode files. This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

delete node modules folder.
and reinstall it again using yarn/npm install

This solved the issue